# Why is an object inside an object not received by the Masstransit consumer when the contract is in a nuget package

Tags: c#, dll, rabbitmq, nuget-package, masstransit

I have a Masstransit publisher and a consumer (both below).

The message that is sent is

```
    public class SendEmailContract
    {
        public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressFrom { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressTo { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressCC { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressBCC { get; internal set; }
        public string Subject { get; internal set; }
        public string Data { get; internal set; }
        public string TemplateCode { get; internal set; }
        public string EmailHtml { get; internal set; }
        public bool WithoutTemplate { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class Attachment
    {
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
        public string ContentType { get; internal set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; internal set; }
    }
```

The email contract has a list of attachments.

When I run the sample publisher the email contract together with the attachments is received by the consumer.

When the email contract is in a nuget package (i.e. in a separate DLL) the email contract is received but the attachments are null.

**Questions** Why is the attachments field null when the contract is in a separate DLL? (the question might be vague, but I do not know how to reduce this problem further, any help and ideas will be greatly appreciated)

Publisher below

```
using MassTransit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsolePublisher
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                });



            });
            var source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            await busControl.StartAsync(source.Token);


            var message = new SendEmailContract
            {
                AddressFrom = "addressfrom@mail.com",
                AddressTo = "addressto@mail.com",
                AddressCC = "cc1@mail.com,cc2@email.com",
                AddressBCC = "bcc1@mail.com,bcc2@mail.com,bcc3@mail.com",
                Subject = $"Test subject email {DateTime.Now}",
                Data = @"<Data><CustomerName>NewReg NewReg</CustomerName><Barcode>bc12345678us</Barcode><URL>https://example.com</URL><ServiceTitle>Priority</ServiceTitle></Data>",
                TemplateCode = "emailtemplate123",
                EmailHtml = "emailhtml",
                WithoutTemplate = false,
                Attachments = new List<Attachment>
                {
                    new Attachment
                    {
                        Name = "Attachment1.txt",
                        ContentType = "txt",
                        Content = new byte[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6},
                    },
                    new Attachment
                    {
                        Name = "Attachment2.txt",
                        ContentType = "txt",
                        Content = new byte[] { 2,2,3,4,5,7},
                    }
                },
            };
            await busControl.Publish<SendEmailContract>(message);


            await busControl.StopAsync();

        }


    }

    public class SendEmailContract
    {
        public string AddressFrom { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressTo { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressCC { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressBCC { get; internal set; }
        public string Subject { get; internal set; }
        public string Data { get; internal set; }
        public string TemplateCode { get; internal set; }
        public string EmailHtml { get; internal set; }
        public bool WithoutTemplate { get; internal set; }
        public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class Attachment
    {
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
        public string ContentType { get; internal set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

Consumer below

```
using GreenPipes;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.ConsumeConfigurators;
using MassTransit.Definition;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ConsuleConsumer
{


    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {

                x.AddConsumer<EmailConsumer>(typeof(EmailConsumerDefinition));
                x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("rabbitmq://localhost");
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });

            });


            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var bus = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>();

            await bus.StartAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            await Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey());

            Console.WriteLine("Now stopping bus...");
            await bus.StopAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Bus stopped");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


    public class EmailConsumer :
IConsumer<ConsolePublisher.SendEmailContract>
    {
        readonly ILogger<EmailConsumer> _logger;

        public EmailConsumer ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("starting email consumer");
        }
        public EmailConsumer(ILogger<EmailConsumer> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ConsolePublisher.SendEmailContract> context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Email:", context.Message.Data);

        }
    }

    public class EmailConsumerDefinition :
    ConsumerDefinition<EmailConsumer>
    {
        public EmailConsumerDefinition()
        {
            // override the default endpoint name
            EndpointName = "email-service";

        }

        protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
            IConsumerConfigurator<EmailConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
        {
            endpointConfigurator.UseScheduledRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));

            endpointConfigurator.UseInMemoryOutbox();
        }
    }

}

namespace ConsolePublisher
{
    public class SendEmailContract
    {
        public string AddressFrom { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressTo { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressCC { get; internal set; }
        public string AddressBCC { get; internal set; }
        public string Subject { get; internal set; }
        public string Data { get; internal set; }
        public string TemplateCode { get; internal set; }
        public string EmailHtml { get; internal set; }
        public bool WithoutTemplate { get; internal set; }
        public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class Attachment
    {
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
        public string ContentType { get; internal set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; internal set; }
    }

}



}
```

Versions using in the publisher

1. MassTransit.RabbitMQ 8.0.5

Versions using in the consumer

1. MassTransit.RabbitMQ 7.0.6

---

**Update**

1. If I use MassTransit.RabbitMQ 7.0.6 in the publisher the problem is solved.
2. When the publisher uses version 8.0.5, if I switch off the consumer and get the messages in the RabbitMQ website (http://localhost:15672/) then the attachments are missing.

Answer (score 1):

MassTransit v8 uses System.Text.Json by default, which will not deserialize into `internal set;` methods. It's also called out in the [documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/messages#classes). You should `{ get; set; }` to ensure properties are properly serialized and deserialized.

> When the class is in the NuGet package, it's no longer "internal" to the application.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this by adding `options.IncludeFields = true;` to the Json Serializer Options when configuring RabbitMQ at startup

```
                cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializerOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.IncludeFields = true;
                    options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never;
                    return options;
                });
```